# JSON individual item

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am creating a project to evaluate different products with a rating system but as I am new to this and I have several questions.

First, to achieve this objective I created a listview that allows me to display the information in a record in a MySQL database using a JSON code you get from this database.

Right now the project is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/c52m6smg/1/.
My questions are as follows, I can replace the var info by an AJAX call to retrieve the JSON data from an external file or a php file stored on the localhost?

On the other hand, taking this base, I can access the information from each of the records but I can place a rating system in the display that affects precisely the displayed register? Or I should do differently? I've been searching and I saw that one possible option would create a PHP file that retrieve a particular record giving the option, eg `localhost/rating/individualjson.php&search=?`.

Sorry if there is something you stupid questions but I'm trying to learn.
I do not ask code done to implement the project, only information and answers to the questions I ask, recommendations or examples of similar cases that might help.

And finally, I have the following code that gets me all data from the database:

Here the PHP file:

```
<?php

// Error function that stops script processing with die
function error($message){
    $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'result' => 'error',
            'msg' => $message
        )
    );
    die($output);
}

// Round to the nearest 0.5
function roundToNearestHalf($number){
    return round($number * 2) / 2;  
}

// Instantiate database connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'XXX', 'XXX');

// Check that the connection worked
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    error('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// Verify that we have enough post items
if(count($_POST) > 1){
    error('Too many post items received.');
}

// Check that the rating was entered
if(!isset($_POST['rating']) || $_POST['rating'] == ''){
    error('No rating value provided.');
}

// Valid the rating amount that was entered.
if(!preg_match("/[0-5](?:\.5)/", $_POST['rating']) && $_POST['rating'] < 0 && $_POST['rating'] > 5){
    error('Invalid rating provided.');
}

// Check if the user has rated before
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT `ratingid`
    FROM `ratings`
    WHERE `ip` = '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    error('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Tell the user that they have voted already.
if($result->num_rows){
    error('That IP address has already voted, please try using another IP.');
}

// Store the user's rating.
$rating = $db->escape_string($_POST['rating']);

$sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO `ratings`
    (`rating`, `ip`)
    VALUES ('{$rating}', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}')
SQL;

if(!$db->query($sql)){
    error('Unable to insert rating to database [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Get the average rating
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT AVG(`rating`) AS `rating`
    FROM `ratings`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    error('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// Fetch the average rating
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

$rating = $data['rating'];

// Output the average rating for the front end to handle
$output = json_encode(
    array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'rating' => roundToNearestHalf($rating)
    )
);
echo $output;
?>
```

Table from MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
    `ratingid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `rating` FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ip` VARCHAR( 39 ) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`ip`)
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

And here js field:

```
var info = [{
        "id": "1",
        "ISBN": "978487485",
        "titol": "20.000 Leguas de viaje Submarino",
        "autor": "---",
        "any": "1978",
        "descripcio": "asdsadasdafsa",
        "format": "Book",
        "stars": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "ISBN": "978848481",
        "titol": "Intocable",
        "autor": "Philipp",
        "any": "1999",
        "descripcio": "asdadaf",
        "format": "Book",
        "stars": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "ISBN": "884697989",
        "titol": "Baba Ramdev",
        "autor": "Patanjali",
        "any": "2000",
        "descripcio": "Herbal Hand Wash Refill",
        "format": "Book",
        "stars": "3"
    }];


    //pageinit event for first page
//triggers only once
//write all your on-load functions and event handlers pertaining to page1
$(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function () {


    //set up string for adding <li/>
    var li = "";
    //container for $li to be added
    $.each(info, function (i, titol) {
        //add the <li> to "li" variable
        //note the use of += in the variable
        //meaning I'm adding to the existing data. not replacing it.
        //store index value in array as id of the <a> tag
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + titol.titol + '</a></li>';
    });
    //append list to ul
    $("#prof-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
        //wait for append to finish - thats why you use a promise()
        //done() will run after append is done
        //add the click event for the redirection to happen to #details-page
        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //store the information in the next page's data
            $("#details-page").data("info", info[this.id]);
            //change the page # to second page. 
            //Now the URL in the address bar will read index.html#details-page
            //where #details-page is the "id" of the second page
            //we're gonna redirect to that now using changePage() method
            $.mobile.changePage("#details-page");
        });

        //refresh list to enhance its styling.
        $(this).listview("refresh");
    });
});

//use pagebeforeshow
//DONT USE PAGEINIT! 
//the reason is you want this to happen every single time
//pageinit will happen only once
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details-page", function () {
    //get from data - you put this here when the "a" wa clicked in the previous page
    var info = $(this).data("info");
    //string to put HTML in
    var info_view = "";
    //use for..in to iterate through object
    for (var key in info) {
        //Im using grid layout here.
        //use any kind of layout you want.
        //key is the key of the property in the object 
        //if obj = {titol: 'k'}
        //key = titol, value = k
         info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }
    info_view += '<span data-id="'+info['id']+'" class="stars s-'+info['stars']+'" data-default="'+info['stars']+'">0 stars</span>';
    //add this to html
    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
$(function(){
    $('body').on({
        mousemove: function(e){
            var $this = $(this);
            // Calculate number of stars
            var currentMousePosition = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
            var width = $this.width();
            var rounded = Math.round((currentMousePosition/width)*10);

            var starNumber = rounded/2;

            // Remove + add Classes + Store current rating
            $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + starNumber).attr('data-rating', starNumber);
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            var $this = $(this); 
            $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + $this.attr('data-default'));
        },
        click: function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            //Hide the current rating selector
            $this.replaceWith($('<div>', {
             'class': 'loading'
            }));

            // Send the request
            $.post('rating.php',{
                rating: $this.attr('data-rating')
            }, function(d){
                // Handle response
                if(d.result == 'error'){
                    alert(d.msg);
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass().addClass('stars s-' + d.rating).attr('data-default', d.rating)
                    $('.loading').replaceWith($this);
                }
            }, 'json');
        }
    }, '.stars');
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: First, yes, you can retrieve your data from an ajax call. you can use the code above, but I do not know why are you storing your data at the end of the file in the json file. for retrieving it by axaj call, `echo` is enough. Second, for rating, from what I have understand from your question, you have to have another table in your database which stores the id of the record from `registres` and the rate of the user, if your users should log in the system to be able to rate, you also need to store the user id and also maybe date and time of the rate

Comment: you can update each record's rate with another ajax call sending the rate and record id to another php file and send back the result. if you do not have an authentication in your system and everybody can rate, then you have to use cookies or html5 localStorage to generate a unique id for each user first time they visit your site and then recognize and reference them using that id.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Referring to the ratings I know I should create a new table in the database, but I am somewhat confused because it is the first time I work with JSON, web service, MySQL and Javascript. My question made reference to whether it is possible to relate the rating system that I put in the application (jsFiddle) and how I could do it. 
In reference to individual record from json, I edited with error code returned my browser.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have made some changes in your fiddle and you can find my version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmv12rry/1/)

please note that I have removed

```
<span class="stars s-2.5" data-default='2.5'>
  0 stars
</span>
```

section from your `html` and added it to the `javascript` under the `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details-page", function () {` function

because in your original code, you only had one set of stars for all products but with this change you have one set for each product.

and then I have added `"stars":` key for the `info` data-set so that each record will have it's own rate value and then added a `data-id` attribute to the `<span>` for stars and added the value to `data-default` attribute.

with this you can access the rate of each product using it's `data-id` and `data-rating` attributes.

hope this can solve your problem and please update us with the result.

Comment: Thank you! It was just what I was looking for.
Now I have to connect to the database with rating.php file, but does not work because it does not rise in the database MySQL valuation. So far I have created a simple table in the database to prove their performance, later'll join tables valuations and products, the returns per console: "element not found". Referring to rating.php.
I put the code in the post, if you can help me with this you'll be my savior.
Thanks again!

Comment: great. I think this error is not related to you `php` code and it related to you `javascrtip` and is occurring when parsing the returned data in ajax. since you've just posted the `php` code and not the related `javascript`, and your `php` code looks OK, I can not see which section of your code is generating this error. please update your post and include the relevant `javascript` code.

Comment: I put javascript code in the post. Thanks again and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I can not find any errors in your `php` and `javascript` except that the table name in your `sql script` is **rating*, but in your `php` both on `insert` and `select` queries you are using `ratings`. maybe it was a typo! also in your queries you are not specifying the `ratingid` which will cause you generate incorrect results. otherwise everything looks OK!

Comment: Thanks for everything EhsanT, I changed the rating - ratings but I have the same error. Referring to ratingid that you comment, can you explain to me a little more? It's the first time I do an assessment system.

Comment: It was my mistake. in your `ratings` table you have the `ratingid` which is auto increment and primary key which is correct. but you have to add another field which specifies this record is related to which product. assuming that you will have a table for you product and use `ajax` to load them from database, then you have to have something like `productid` field in your `ratings` table so when you add a rating, you have to specify this rating is for which product and also when calculating the `avg` of the ratings, you have to calculate average rating of that specific product.